# Rails routes based on a value in a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Rails 3.1. I have a table `places`. It has a column called `type` which has value such as `cafe`, `restaurant`, etc. Just one value in each row.

In my routes, I define the resources as:

```
resources :places
```

The URL is:

```
http://domain.com/places/123?type=cafe
```

I always have the `type` appended in my URLs because I use that to determine which navigation menu to be highlighted.

Now, I want to create a friendlier URL. How can I create a URL that reads either of these:

```
1. http://domain.com/places/cafe/123
2. http://domain.com/cafe/123
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of routes - resourceful and non-resourceful. It sounds like you're trying to do a mix between the two. Unfortunately, resourceful route URLs can't be customized like you're trying to do via `resources`, but you can add additional routes to match the URLs you're trying to make.

To accomplish this, you'll have to create non-resourceful routes such as these:

```
resources :places, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
match 'places/:type/:id' => 'places#show'
match 'places/:type' => 'places#index'
match 'places/:type/new' => 'places#new'
match 'places/:type/edit' => 'places#edit'
```

You don't need to create special routes for create, update, and destroy (though you could). The user never really sees those anyway. Just include the place type as a parameter in your forms and delete links, and it will be available in the controller the same way that it would as if it were coming from the URL.

In the controller, access the type via `params[:type]`.

Comment: was working on a answer like this. I would just had he warning for spaces in the type and point this gem to solve that https://github.com/Sutto/slugged

Comment: Actually, having spaces in the type in the URL works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the value stored in `@place.type`, where `@place = Place.find params[:id]`, to determine which navigation to use?

Comment: Although this isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, he's right.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although this is easier to do, I would stick with the url, because it adds more semantic to it. Just because it's the menu, and I think url should have information about in what menu user is.